# Insert multiple data return from http API into sql lite

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sqlite, typescript, ionic2

I'm working on an ionic2 project which users have to login in first to get access to the system.
When they login and its succesfully i then post thier username to a different API to get a list of all entries made by them after which i want to insert all the returned entries into an sql lite db but i'm finding it hard to do

```
userlogin(){

    let loader = this.LoadingController.create({
      content: 'Please Wait'
      });
      loader.present().then(()=>{

    this.http.post("http://localhost/app/login.php", { 'username': this.username, 'password': this.password }).map(res => res.json()) .subscribe(data => {

      if(data.message!="Incorrect Username or Password"){

     this.http.post("http://localhost/app/entries.php", { 'username': this.username}).map(res => res.json()) .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

      this.sqlite.create({
        name: 'entries.db',
        location: 'default'
        })
        .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
        //data insert section
        db.executeSql('INSERT INTO entries_table(entry) VALUES(?)', 
        [this.data.entry]).then((data)=> {

        }, (error) => {

        });


        })
     });



    }else{

    if(data.message=="Incorrect Username or Password"){
      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Error!',
        subTitle: 'Wrong Username or Password',
        buttons: ['Try Again']
      });
      alert.present();
    }
    }
    loader.dismiss();
    });

  },error=>{
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Error!',
      subTitle: 'Please check your Internet Connectivity',
      buttons: ['Try Again']
    });
    alert.present();
  }) 
  }
```

Logging In works fine but the issue is inserting the multiple data returned by the API at a time into the sql lite db

Answer (score 1):

Use ionic storage and configure the driver to use sqlite. then it's simple

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

export class MyApp {
  constructor(private storage: Storage) { }

  ...

  // set a key/value
  storage.set('entries', returnedEntryObject);

  // Or to get a key/value pair
  storage.get('entires')
    .then((returnedEntryObject) => {
        console.log('The user entries are', returnedEtnryObject);
  });
}
```

You can check the details indeep on this [link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/).